Why do multiply electric field by the area?
I have a question about why we multiply e field by the surface area. When finding the total of something in a given area we need to take how much there is in one unit and multiply it by the area. If i want to find the total charge in an area i dint take the charge and multiply it by the area. I need to take the darge density and multiply it by the area . So why do we take the e field and not the e field per unit and multiply it by the area?

Are you talking about flux? flux is defined as E.ds

If I want to find the total charge in an area I didn't take the charge and multiply it by the area. I needed to take the [surface] charge density and multiply it by the area.
When you are multiplying the electric field (a vector quantity) by an area you are obtaining a measure of something (in this case the electric field) passing through an area, a flow (flux) through the area.
There is no flow associated with charges (a scalar quantity) resident in an area.
